# Save an image with $_POST['name_surname'] in PHP (from input)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Signature Pad source code, this system save the signatures in one folder (with .png extension), but work only via md5.

```
<?php 
$result = array();
$imagedata = base64_decode($_POST['img_data']);
$filename = md5(date("dmYhisA"));
//Location to where you want to created sign image
$file_name = './doc_signs/'.$filename.'.png';
file_put_contents($file_name,$imagedata);
$result['status'] = 1;
$result['file_name'] = $file_name;
echo json_encode($result);
```

?>

In the homepage I have the signature pad, and one "input" in html with name "nome_cognome_cliente"

```
<input name="nome_cognome_cliente" type="text" required="true" placeholder="Nome e Cognome"><br><br>
```

I would like save the signatures files with the name that user write in it.

I tested to write this in $filename variable. But doesn't work... where am i wrong? Thanks for helping.

```
$filename = $_POST['nome_cognome_cliente'];
```

Also, I would like save this signatures (images) in one Database with the date of entry (DD/MM/YYYY).

Comment: I doesn't look like your parsing the image data correctly. See the upload example [here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-signature-pad-example-e-signature-pad-using-jquery-ajax-and-phpexample.html)

Comment: @Jamie_D thanks for the source code, but in it I see "unique id" in PHP. I would like save the signatures with a text (inserted by user in a input/label).